# Apply multiple classes for one condtion in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have 2 classes in and collapse and I want to apply both classes for same condition in angular js.

ex.

```
data-ng-class="{'in collapse': review.status != 'completed' && review.status != 'signedOff'"
```

can any one have idea how I can apply with this ?

Comment: which version of angular you are using because answer will change based on version of angular you are using

Comment: I am using latest version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually what you were doing is completely valid, you just forgot a closing curly bracket `}`

```
data-ng-class="{'in collapse': review.status != 'completed' && review.status != 'signedOff'}"
```

Comment: yes its working for me but can I shorten down this something like
<span ng-class="{'in collapse':(review.status!='comp'&& review.status!='signedOff'>